# Difference between ShadowLooper.idle() and ShadowLooper.runToEndOfTasks()

Tags: android, robolectric, android-looper

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between calling [`idle()`](https://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.1/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowLooper.html#idle--) and [`runToEndOfTasks()`](https://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.1/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowLooper.html#runToEndOfTasks--) on a looper.

Based on the documentation, it seems the main difference if whether the scheduler's clock is advanced (it isn't in case of `idle()`), but other than that it seems both will result in all scheduled `Runnable`s to run.

Does this mean `idle()` runs everything except runnables scheduled via `postDelayed()`? What's the behavior of `runToEndOfTasks()` if something is repeating forever (e.g. `postDelayed()` called inside itself)?